# rspec Ruby Method to insert into Hash

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm having trouble figuring out this challenge.  Here is what I have:

```
class Dictionary
attr_accessor :entries

def initialize
    @x = Hash.new
end

def entries
    @x
end

def add(hash)
    @x.merge!(hash)
end

end

@d=Dictionary.new
@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
puts @d.entries
```

i'm getting => "fishaquatic animal"

I'm WANTING to get => {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_s` on `Hash` behaves less-than-ideally for some Ruby versions. Try `puts @d.entries.inspect`.

**Update:**

The following code works for me (Ruby 1.9.3 and rspec 2.12.0):

```
class Dictionary      
  def initialize
    @x = Hash.new
  end

  def entries
    @x
  end

  def add(hash)
    @x.merge!(hash)
  end
end

describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
  end
end
```

Comment: that did it!! only this is...i'm trying to satisfy an rpec code...and they have it `@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')` ...any ideas? thanks @Levi

Comment: I updated the answer with an example test that works for me. Do you get different behavior?

Comment: this one works..thanks!! the only difference i see is that your code here does not have `attr_accessor :entries` , do you know why that caused a different result?

Comment: The `attr_accessor` shouldn't matter. If you add that back in at the top of the class does it break again?

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code is currently setting @x to a new, empty Hash and then returning it every time you call the `entries` method.

Try moving that setup code into an initialize method:

```
class Dictionary
    attr_reader :entries

    def initialize
        @entries = Hash.new
    end

    def add(hash)
        @entries.merge!(hash) 
    end
end
```

Comment: thanks great pointer....tried running that...still getting an error "wrong number of arguments"

Comment: i'm getting it here:@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
@d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}

Comment: Hm, can you paste what your `add` method looks like currently?

Comment: im trying the one you posted...and the command:                     `@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')                              @d.entries    ` hoping to get => `{'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}`

Comment: It seems to work correctly when I try it in an irb session, not sure why the rspec test wouldn't be working at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like to me the rspec codes a bit weird. The second test does an entries method, and the entries method resets the instance variable @x back to blank.  So it would better to add the instance variable as an attr_reader and then initialize it when you make a new dictionary object.  So it would look something like this

```
class Dictionary
    attr_reader @x

    def initialize
      @x = Hash.new
    end

    def add(hash)
      @x.merge!(hash) 
    end
end
```

and the test would be like this

```
@d.add(fish: "aquatic animal")
@d.x.should == {'fish' => "aquatic animal"}
```